# asp.net:query with multiple where conditions

Tags: mysql, asp.net

**1.** I have query.But couldn't  add second where condition.Please suggest me the correct semantic .

**2.** And how can fetch the data from dropdownlist and show it in gridview.

**3.** How can i fetch value from `Tution fee` Column of my database when  condition satisfies ,and `Hostel Fee` on fail of condition.??

```
protected void BindGridview()
{
    constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring_DETMIS"].ToString(); // connection string
                                                                                  // String FID = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    using (var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(constr)) {
        conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("select * from fees_collect_category" + " where F_id =" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value " and C_id=" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value, conn)) {

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                if (reader.HasRows) {
                    gvDetails.DataSource = reader;
                    gvDetails.DataBind();
                } else
                    lblWarning.Text = "There are no records..";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `+` in front of `" and C_id="`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to **Stackoverflow**. You should first research on the google as why you are not able to add *multiple* conditions(It's just because of simple **syntax** mistake).

The exact code of line would be something like this.

```
using (var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("select * from fees_collect_category" +
                                                      " where F_id = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "' and C_id=" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value + "'", conn))
```

**NOTE**:- As a fellow developer, I won't suggest you to do this by passing values from here as it is dangerous and prone to [SQL INJECTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

I would rather tell you to go by using [Parameterized queries](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx)

Hope that helps and for future go for the Parametrized ones, as it is easy and technically preffered.

Comment: Thank you all .I found my mistake.Its silly thing!! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void BindGridview()
        {
            String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["connstring_DETMIS"].ConnectionString;
            String strQuery = "select * from student_details " +
                               "where F_id=@F_Id and C_id=@C_Id";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(strConnString);

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@F_Id",
                DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Id",
                DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                gvDetails.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                gvDetails.DataBind();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```